# NIntegrate warning: The integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity with boundaries

Tags: numerical-integration

The code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 110.; b = 55.; d = 1.; m1 = 18.; m2 = 42.; m = m2/m1; 
n = 10;
deltap = .8;
inipoint = 3.;
tlength = 1.14;
w[lam_, xi_] := -((m1*a)/2) Log[1 -(lam^(-4) + 2*lam^2 - 3)/a] - (m2*b)/2 Log[1 - (lam^-4*xi^4 + 2 lam^2*xi^-2 - 3)/b]
    dw[lam_, xi_] := D[w[lam, xi], lam]
    f[lam_, xi_] := dw[lam, xi]/(1 - lam^3)
    sup[x_] := ((d + x^3)/(1 + d))^(1/3)

intf[x_Real, xi_] := 
 NIntegrate[f[lam, xi], {lam, x, sup[x]}, 
  Exclusions -> (x0 /. NSolve[Denominator[Together@f[x0, xi]] == 0, x0]), 
  Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
eq1 := x[t]*x''[t] (1 - (1 + d/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) + 
    1/2 x'[t]^2 (3 - d/x[t]^3 (1 + d/x[t]^3)^(-4/3) - 
       3 (1 + d/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) + intf[x[t], xi[t]] == deltap;
eq2 := xi'[t]/
    xi[t] == (m (x[t]^2*xi[t]^-2 - 
        x[t]^-4*xi[t]^4))/(3 n*(1 - (x[t]^-4*xi[t]^4 + 
           2 x[t]^2*xi[t]^-2 - 3)/b));

sol = Timing@
   NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, xi[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
     x[0] == inipoint}, {x[t], xi[t]}, {t, 0, tlength}];
```

when the "inipoint" is set to be 3, it gives the result
[image: For inipoin=3.]

However, when "inipoint=4.", the warning is
NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,1.68335*10^-22}}.

Someone has ideas about it? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is possible to lower the integration time by three orders, using `GaussianQuadratureWeights` instead of `NIntegrate`. Check that the following code is executed in 0.046875 sec and has the same output like the original code that runs 51.0781 sec (on my laptop):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
\[Alpha] = 110.; \[Beta] = 55.; \[Delta] = 1.; \[Mu]1 = 18.; \[Mu]2 = \
42.; \[Mu] = \[Mu]2/\[Mu]1;
\[Eta]b = 10;
deltap = .8;
inipoint = 3.;
tlength = 1.14;
w[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_] := -((\[Mu]1*\[Alpha])/2) Log[
    1 - (\[Lambda]^(-4) + 2*\[Lambda]^2 - 
        3)/\[Alpha]] - (\[Mu]2*\[Beta])/2 Log[
    1 - (\[Lambda]^-4*\[Xi]^4 + 2 \[Lambda]^2*\[Xi]^-2 - 3)/\[Beta]]
dw[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_] := D[w[\[Lambda], \[Xi]], \[Lambda]]
f[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_] := dw[\[Lambda], \[Xi]]/(1 - \[Lambda]^3)
sup[x_] := ((\[Delta] + x^3)/(1 + \[Delta]))^(1/3)
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
np = 11; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}];

intf[x0_, \[Xi]0_] := 
 Block[{y = x0, \[Xi]1 = \[Xi]0}, 
  Do[points[[i]] = 
    GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, y, sup[y]][[i, 1]], {i, 1, np}];
  Do[weights[[i]] = 
    GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, y, sup[y]][[i, 2]], {i, 1, np}]; 
  int = Sum[(f[\[Lambda], \[Xi]1] /. \[Lambda] -> points[[i]])*
     weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}]; int]
eq1 := x''[t] + (1/
          2 x'[t]^2 (3 - \[Delta]/
             x[t]^3 (1 + \[Delta]/x[t]^3)^(-4/3) - 
           3 (1 + \[Delta]/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) + intf[x[t], \[Xi][t]] - 
        deltap)/x[t]/(1 - (1 + \[Delta]/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) == 0;
eq2 := \[Xi]'[
    t] == \[Xi][
     t]*(\[Mu] (x[t]^2*\[Xi][t]^-2 - 
         x[t]^-4*\[Xi][t]^4))/(3 \[Eta]b*(1 - (x[t]^-4*\[Xi][t]^4 + 
            2 x[t]^2*\[Xi][t]^-2 - 3)/\[Beta]));


sol = Timing@
  NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, \[Xi][0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
    x[0] == inipoint}, {x[t], \[Xi][t]}, {t, 0, tlength}]
```

Figure 1 shows `x[t]` (1) and $\xi (t)$ (2) for `inipoint=3`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], \[Xi][t]} /. Last[sol]], {t, 0, tlength}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"inipoint = ", inipoint}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]
Construct a parametric function

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, \[Xi][0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
   x[0] == p}, {x[tlength], \[Xi][tlength]}, {t, 0, tlength}, {p}]
```

Then we have

```
pfun[3]

(*Out[]= {1.43111, 0.826233}*)
```

Figure 2 shows the dependence of functions `{x[tlength], \[Xi][tlength]}` on the parameter `p`. We see that when `p>3.5095592`, instability is observed.

```
Plot[pfun[p], {p, 2, 3.5}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Compare the solution with `p=3.5095592` and with `p=3.5095595`on fig.3. We see that the instability develops during the first rebound at `x[t]-> 0`.

[image: Figure 3]

To make sure that this is a numerical instability, we use an explicit method with a very small step. Figure 4 shows that it is possible to pass the first bounce at `inipoint=3.6`.

```
eq11 = {x'[t] == y[t], 
  y'[t] + (1/
          2 y[t]^2 (3 - \[Delta]/
             x[t]^3 (1 + \[Delta]/x[t]^3)^(-4/3) - 
           3 (1 + \[Delta]/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) + intf[x[t], \[Xi][t]] - 
        deltap)/x[t]/(1 - (1 + \[Delta]/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) == 
   0}; eq21 = \[Xi]'[
   t] == \[Xi][
    t]*(\[Mu] (x[t]^2*\[Xi][t]^-2 - 
        x[t]^-4*\[Xi][t]^4))/(3 \[Eta]b*(1 - (x[t]^-4*\[Xi][t]^4 + 
           2 x[t]^2*\[Xi][t]^-2 - 3)/\[Beta]));

sol11 = Timing@
  NDSolve[{eq11, eq2, \[Xi][0] == 1, y[0] == 0, 
    x[0] == 3.6}, {x[t], \[Xi][t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tlength}, 
   Method -> "ExplicitEuler", MaxStepSize -> 1/5000000, 
   MaxSteps -> 10^7]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], \[Xi][t]} /. Last[sol11]], {t, 0, tlength}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"inipoint = ", 3.6}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Fugure 4]

Comment: That's a great job you've done! But when I use the `NIntegrate` function and change the interval `xlist = Range[5, 8, 0.002]` from 0.002 to 0.001 or other smaller values for the code below, Clear["Global`*"] \[Alpha] = 110.; \[Beta] = 55.; \[Delta] = 1; \[Mu] = 42/18; f[\[Lambda]_] := ((2*(\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^(-5)))/(1 - \ (\[Lambda]^(-4) + 2*\[Lambda]^2 - 3)/\[Alpha]) + (2*\[Mu] (\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^(-5)))/(1 - (\[Lambda]^(-4) + 2*\[Lambda]^2 - 3)/\[Beta]))/(1 - \[Lambda]^3) sup[x_] := ((\[Delta] + x^3)/(1 + \[Delta]))^(1/3) xlist = Range[5, 8, 0.002]; (***the change of inte

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have the similar problem with codes listed below in the "answer part", would you mind to give some more suggestions?

Comment: There is a suspicion that this integral is calculated incorrectly. Therefore, I replaced `NIntegrate[]` with `Sum[]` using `GaussianQuadratureWeights`.